# Python get data from secured website

Tags: python, post, cookies, get, urllib2

Id like to know if there is a way to get information from my banking website with Python, Id like to retrieve my card history and display it, and possibly save it into a text document each month.

I have found the urls ext to login and get the information from the website, which works from a browser, but I have been using liburl2 to "open" the webpages from Python and I have a feeling its not working because of some cookie or session things.

I can get any information I want from a website that does not require a login with urllib2, and then save the actual HTML and go through it later, but I cant on my banks website,

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is likely to be difficult. You may have some luck using a browser harness framework to actually load the page in a browser and fill in the form fields yourself.

Comment: I have come across this http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ - is this a browser harness framework?

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html may be worth a look.

Comment: Try [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Comment: At a minimum, use http://python-requests.org/ rather than urllib2; it greatly reduces the boilerplate that has to be written.

Comment: @JasonRussell Posting "feeling its not working because of some cookie or session things." doesn't provide us any info on what you tried and what the error or result was.

Answer (score 3):

This is a part of *Web-Scraping* :

- Web-scraping is a standard task that can serve various needs.
- Scraping data out of secure-website means `https`
- Handling `https` is not a problem with `mechanize` and `BeautifulSoup`
- Although `urllib2` with `HTTPCookieJar` also works fine
- If managing the cookies is the problem, then I would recommend `mechanize`

Considering the case of your BANK-Site :

1. I would recommend not to play with your account.
2. If you must then, its not as easy as any normal secure/non-secure site.
3. These sites are designed to with-stand such scripts.

Problems that you would face with this:

1. BANK sites will surely have Captcha that is almost impossible to by-pass with a script unless you employee a lot of rocket-science and effort.
2. Other problem that you will definitely face is javascript, standard scripting solutions are focused to manage cookies, HTML parsing, etc. For processing javascript on links you will have to process `js` in your python script. That again needs a lot of effort.
3. Then, `AJAX` that again comes from javascript fetches data from server after page-load.

So, it will require you to take a lot of effort to do this task.

**Also, if you try doing this you risk of blocking access to your account since banking sites are quick to block account access on 3-4 unsuccessful attempt on login or captcha, etc.**

So, think before you do.

Comment: If you have your username and password in the script can't you just pass them to the website to access your data? Isn't that how websites like Mint.com work?